# Why is this sequence not acceptable for this DFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Why is the sequence 1100101 not acceptable for this DFA? Is it because once it reaches the final state 'q3' it can't go back to 'q1'?[image]

Comment: It's because the run is $q_0,q_3,q_3,q_1,q_0,q_3,q_1,q_2$, and $q_2$ is not accepting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon reading the word 1100101, the DFA reaches the non-accepting state $q_2$. There's nothing more to it.

A DFA accepts a word $w$ if when starting for the initial state and following the transitions according to $w$, the DFA reaches a state $q$ which is accepting. If it reaches a state which is not accepting, it rejects $w$. This is the definition of acceptance for DFAs.

Comment: Would q2 need to be a final state for it to accept?

Comment: Exactly, The only final state in your automaton is $q_3$. Final states also go by the name "accepting states".